# Job scheduler stops working if app killed android

Tags: android, job-scheduling, android-backup-service, android-jobscheduler

Hi did a sample of `JobScheduler` in my app.
This is how I initiate it

```
jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
ComponentName jobService = new ComponentName(getPackageName(),
        MyJobService.class.getName());
JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(MYJOBID, jobService)
        .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
        .setExtras(bundle).build();
jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
```

And I showed a toast in the `JobService`:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class MyJobService extends JobService {

public MyJobService() {
}

@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {

   // UtilityMethods.showToast(this,params.getExtras().getString("json"));
    Toast.makeText(this,"test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    UtilityMethods.showToast(this,"onStop()");
    return false;
}

}
```

And this was working perfectly fine even I tried turning off the internet and killing app from background.
I then tried building a similar thing in one of my libraries. I wrote the same code in the library and I am calling it from my app's `MainActivity`. But this time, When I kill app from background, it stops working. Can anyone tell me why?

**My `MainActivity` where I initialize it**

```
JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
ComponentName jobService = new ComponentName(getPackageName(),
        MyJobService.class.getName());
JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(MYJOBID, jobService)
        .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY).build();
jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
```

It is working when I start it from onCreate and not working if I start it from a callback funtion().

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Android> 7 automatically saves battery power. You must enable the app's battery saver stop

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            String packageName = getPackageName();
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
            if (!pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
```

add this to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
```

Comment: Yes this will only work , rather than restarting service or job or alarm or anything from destroy or other cheeky methods , nothing will work except this

Answer (score 2):

Make this return true

```
@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {

   // UtilityMethods.showToast(this,params.getExtras().getString("json"));
    Toast.makeText(this,"test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return true;
}
```

and start a new thread from here(as this is executed on mainthread only).

```
onStartJob

added in API level 21
boolean onStartJob (JobParameters params)
Override this method with the callback logic for your job. Any such logic needs to be performed on a separate thread, as this function is executed on your application's main thread.

Parameters
params  JobParameters: Parameters specifying info about this job, including the extras bundle you optionally provided at job-creation time.
Returns
boolean True if your service needs to process the work (on a separate thread). False if there's no more work to be done for this job.
```

Comment: i didn't understand.. how can that ork? can you please explain?

Comment: I've added explanation from google page, please let me know if it's not clear to you.

Comment: It is working on real device like redmi. Can someone able to solve the problem?

Comment: it will not run any background task if you use Workmanager, jobScheduler ,Service or IntentService Because Chinese manufacturer Clean all background task when user closes app from recent app but if you use Periodic task it will work after certain intervals